# WebClient Download File Working Incorrectly

Tags: c#, download, webclient

Hi Everyone I Am Trying To Write a Game Patcher so i am downloading a file to find the version i have done a lot of research of what code should be used all the different method result in the same

```
            WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient();
            Uri url = new Uri("http://theblademasterrpg.com/Patcher/data/p.dat");
            downloadClient.DownloadFile(url, Application.StartupPath + "\\p2.dat");
            downloadClient.Dispose();
            FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\p2.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            string fileContents;
            using (StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                fileContents = reader1.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

The File Appear to Download but its not correct this file only has text in it like 1.0

it always shows this no matter what i do even changing it to html file

[image]

i cant help but think it is something webserver related so i tried apache instead of iis with the same result

has anyone else expirenced this i would rather download http and avoid ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website is not going to give that file that easy to you. You need to parse that initial response a bit, you're looking for this string:

```
<frame src="http://71.82.23.25:8080/Patcher/data/p.dat" name="redir_frame"  frameborder="0">
```

And then call `DownloadString` again but now with the url in that `src` attribute:

This code does a quick hack with string `IndexOf` to find that attribute.

```
 using(WebClient downloadClient = new WebClient())
 {
    Uri url = new Uri("http://theblademasterrpg.com/Patcher/data/p.dat");
    var html= downloadClient.DownloadString(url);
    // parse to the frame src
    var search = "<frame src=\"";
    var pos = html.IndexOf(search);
    // find the end quote
    var lastQuote = html.IndexOf("\"", pos+ search.Length);
    // download that src
    var frameUrl = html.Substring(pos+ search.Length, lastQuote- (pos + search.Length));
    var real = downloadClient.DownloadString(frameUrl);
    // real has now the content of that file
    real.Dump(); // LinQPad
 }
```

Do note that of the website changes their html markup you need to adapt this code accordingly.

Comment: Thank You i Understand now, because im hosting myself and masking my url it wasnt correct in a way ^.^ thanks for the response